# How to load several files in the same arrays in python with loadtxt?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several table files and I load them with :

```
x, y, rho, phi = np.loadtxt(myfile, unpack=True)
```

Now, consider the case where I have `myfile1` and `myfile2` with the same format. How to load them in the same arrays (as if there was one file) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this (e.g., you could load both arrays then concatenate them via `x = numpy.concatenate((x1, x2))`, etc.), but what I'd do is concatenate the files on the fly, and pass the result to `loadtxt`.

As [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) says, `fname` can be:

> File, filename, or generator to read. If the filename extension is .gz or .bz2, the file is first decompressed. Note that generators should return byte strings for Python 3k.

So, you just need a generator that generates myfile1, then myfile2.

The obvious way to do this is with `itertools`:

```
with open(myfile1, 'rb') as f1, open(myfile2, 'rb') as f2:
  x, y, rho, phi = numpy.loadtxt(itertools.chain(f1, f2))
```

You may notice that I left off the `unpack=True`. That's because `unpack` only works if you pass a filename, not a file object or generator. (It looks at the extension, not the file magic or anything fancy.)

If you know the files will *always* be gzip or bzip2 files, you can just substitute `gzip.GzipFile` or `bz2.BZ2File` for `open` above.

But if you need to deal with *possibly* compressed files, you have to do the same extension-checking that `numpy` does, then create the appropriate object (write a `open_compressed` function that wraps that up), at which point this becomes stubbornly sticking to the wrong solution. So, if that's an issue, I'd probably go with loading them separately and then doing `numpy.concatenate`.

Comment: Well, yours works for more than two files. I really wish there were a "with expression" in Python, so you could do the whole thing as a single generator instead of a `with` block with a generator inside (or vice-versa, as in your version).

Comment: I just realized one problem with this solution: If `myfile1 == 'foo.txt.bz2'`, this will iterate line by line through a compressed file… which will generally work (with `'rb'` mode), but the lines could be gigantic, which could conceivably be a problem. I just tested by creating random big arrays and gzipping them until I got a 67K line, and it seemed to work fine, but it might be worth more strenuous testing.

Comment: Something like `foo.readlines() with open(...) as foo`?  That would be a little crazy ...

Comment: Does this really work at all with zipped files?  You're not passing the filename, you're passing a file object.  Does numpy check file objects and decompress the input stream on the fly?  That would be kind of cool...As an aside, your itertools.chain will remove any filename information that was stored in your file-object that numpy might have been able to check.  I doubt you're getting the same random array you put in (but you could check).

Comment: @mgilson: Actually, I didn't test with numpy, I tested more indirectly… and no, it doesn't work, unless you get very lucky… So, another problem with the answer. As for the syntax for the with expression, yeah, that's the tricky part. My idea was that it would have to appear inside a generator expression, so more like `line for line in foo with open(…) as foo`, but it's still ugly enough that I haven't thought it worth writing a PEP, because I know Guido would barf on it.

Comment: @PEP's aren't written in a day.  I think they're usually discussed on the python mailing lists for quite some time before people settle in on a reasonable syntax.  You could probably look around and see if there's already a PEP for this in discussion (It wouldn't surprise me).

Comment: @mgilson: I brought the idea up on either python-ideas or python-dev a few years ago, and nobody came up with any better syntax, but the idea keeps coming back to me every time I run into a problem that would be an obvious one-liner expression (and still could be if you rely on refcounting semantics…), but instead has to be a statement.

Comment: Is it also possible to read in several txt files within one zip-file using this approach?

Comment: @HyperCube: Well, you'd have to open a `zipfile.ZipFile`, then iterate and concatenate its contents. Something like (off the top of my head, not tested) `with zipfile.ZipFile(myzippath) as myzipfile: numpy.loadtxt(itertools.chain(myzipfile.open(name) for name in myzipfile.namelist()))`—but that's relying on the fact that closing a `ZipFile` closes its contained files, which may not be true. In which case you need a nested `with` statement. (See, another case where a with expression would be perfect…) If you can't figure out the code from my rambling, ask and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Following: from a quick scan of the code, it looks like closing a `ZipFile` does _not_ close any `ZipExtFile`s you have lying around; they each keep a copy of the underlying file object. (And bad things will happen in write mode, so don't do that…) So, my last comment only works right in CPython, and should never be used even there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use standard fileinput module:

```
import fileinput
import glob
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(fileinput.input(glob.glob("*.dat")))
```

Comment: +1. I always forget that `fileinput` can be used for more than just the default "`sys.argv[1:]` or stdin" case…